# Handsontable autocomplete source from settings object (for each cell)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handsontable

guys.

I am trying to get my autocomplete settings for each cell from an object. Pointing the data attributes of each object using the property name from an object works for all other types, but not for the "options" of an autocomplete. Here's an example of my settings object, which I pass to Handsontable initialisation:

```js
      var settings = {
        columns: [
          {data: 'base_image', type: 'text', renderer: HsCustomRenderers_image},
          {data: 'description', type: 'text', renderer: HsCustomRenderers_text},
          {data: 'name', type: 'text', renderer: HsCustomRenderers_text},
          {data: 'price', type: 'text', renderer: HsCustomRenderers_number},
          {data: 'quantity', type: 'text', renderer: HsCustomRenderers_decimal},
          {data: 'sku', type: 'text', renderer: HsCustomRenderers_text},
          {data: 'status', type: 'text', renderer: HsCustomRenderers_text},
          {type: 'autocomplete', strict: false, source: 'visibility.value.selected')
          // {data: 'visibility.value.selected', type: 'autocomplete', strict: false},
        ],
        colHeaders: ['Image', 'Descriptions', 'Name', 'Price', 'Quantity', 'SKU', 'Status', 'Visibility']
        // More settings to follow
      };
```

I am talking about the last row of the object, and particularly this part:

source: 'visibility.value.selected'

In the data object, this is an array, but when passed to Handontable, it is passed as a string, which stops it from working :(

Here is how I initialise HOT in my Angular directive's link function:

```js
        var hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('datagrid'), {
          data: scope.gridData,
          rowHeaders: true,
          colHeaders: settings.colHeaders,
          contextMenu: true,
          columns: settings.columns
        });
```

This object is going to be returned from an API, and is currently in my Angular controller. Maybe I should parse the property in the controller?

P.S.: I'm sorry for not such good english, and will supply more details and code if necessary!

Comment: why are you passing it as a string? of course you have to parse it, but not in the controller, parse it on the JS side

Answer (score 1):

Yes, parse it on the JS side, a string as a source won't work. You can use something like

```
JSON.parse(dataFromServer)
```

That should parse it into an object which you should then modify to fit the `sources` format.